# hyperlinking a list item?

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

i know this might seem straightforward, but i can't solve it, im trying to make the whole list item linkable, rather than just the word `home`

the html code:

```
<a href="#page1"><li class="current">Home</li></a>
```

p.s. when you hover the li, background color changes, so i want that whole list item to be hyperlinked, if you get what i mean, not just the word

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrapping a block level element (the `li`) within an inline-element (`a`), is invalid mark-up, which has the potential to throw errors, depending on your doctype. That being the case, first change your mark-up around to:

```
<li><a href="#">link text</a></li>
```

Assuming that your `li` is `display: block` then the following will cause the `a` to 'fill' the available space:

```
a {
 display: block;
 width: 100%; /* this may, or may not, be necessary */
}
```

If you're using this for a horizontal list, and the `li` are `display: inline`, then you can use the following:

```
a {
  display: inline-block;
  }
```

And style-to-taste.

Answer (score 1):

Do it in reverse

```
<li class="current"><a href="#page1">Home</a></li>
```

not sure what your other styles are but you can change the  tag with something like

```
li.current a{
  display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

HTML:

```
<li class="current"><a href="#page1">Home</a></li>
```

CSS:

```
li a {
    display: block;
}

// or

li.current a {
    display: block;
}
```

​